# How to make a <?php if statement work in <script>

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, joomla, joomla-k2

I'm adding a map system i designed to be used in joomla K2 module. The Joomla system currently uses the following code to output information for each item.

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($item2->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
    <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
        <?php if($extraField->type == 'header'): ?>
            <h4 class="itemExtraFieldsHeader"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></h4>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

the output looks like the following:

- First Name:   George
- Last Name:   Ramsay
- Park Section:   Garden of Tranquility
- Burial Plot:   D15

Now within a file called default.php, i have input the following codes to display the map. Now that this is done, i need it to create a popup within the map that displays information on each item/person. i plan on doing this using the php codes previously mentioned. Heres an example of what it should look like http://visuarch.net/map/dovecot-map.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
      function init() {
        var mapMinZoom = 3;
        var mapMaxZoom = 8;
        var map = L.map('map', {
          maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
          minZoom: mapMinZoom,

        }).setView([70, -100], mapMaxZoom);

        var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
            map.unproject([0, 27136], mapMaxZoom),
            map.unproject([50176, 0], mapMaxZoom));

        map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
        L.tileLayer('http://visuarch.net/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
          bounds: mapBounds,
          attribution: 'Copyright © 2014 Dovecot of St. James Memorial Park.',
          noWrap: true          
        }).addTo(map);
         map.attributionControl.setPrefix('');

         var plotset3 = [
    [80.1261, -101.7334],
    [80.93535, -90.54932],
    [78.90816, -85.979],
    [77.82332, -96.45996]
];

var plotset4 = [
    [69.95291, -57.78809],
    [68.22052, -69.16992],
    [70.83025, -73.125],
    [72.44879, -61.25977]
];

var plotset5 = [
    [68.24497, -68.18115],
    [68.19605, -60.6665],
    [66.80057, -60.64453],
    [66.86972, -68.20312]
];

var plotset6 = [
    [66.19601, -67.03857],
    [66.39036, -58.97461],
    [60.72694, -53.23975],
    [59.84481, -56.88721],
    [59.22093, -56.25],
    [58.43623, -59.43604]
];


var plotset = L.polygon([ plotset3, plotset4, plotset5, plotset6], {
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
}).addTo(map);
    var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([73.64017, -100.32715])
    .setContent( "<h4><center><b>JOHN DOE</b></center></h4> <center><img src='http://visuarch.net/dovecot/media/k2/items/cache/48ee1e8a0a8f50dce4f8cb9ab418e211_XS.jpg' border='1px'> </center><br>Section:<b> Park Section</b> <br> Plot ID:<b> J15</b>"


                      )

    .openOn(map);
      }

      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            init();
      });

    </script>
```

this is the code i used for the example:

```
var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([73.64017, -100.32715])
    .setContent( "<h4><center><b>JOHN DOE</b></center></h4> <center><img src='http://visuarch.net/dovecot/media/k2/items/cache/48ee1e8a0a8f50dce4f8cb9ab418e211_XS.jpg' border='1px'> </center><br>Section:<b> Park Section</b> <br> Plot ID:<b> J15</b>")
    .openOn(map);
```

I just need to know how to use the php in the .setContent section to output the information i need.

Please help!!!

Be as detailed as possible i'm not great at javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: it would appear that .setContent is injecting html on the client side since javascript runs on the client.  Php runs on the server side, so I dont' think you can do what you are trying to do and have it work the way you expect it to  work.

Comment: Interesting.... So what would you recommend i do? @dboals how can i call and output the information?

Comment: Some ajax could do the job. It would call a php script which would get whatever data you want.

Comment: Ok, dont lookdown at me, but could you give me details on exactly what to do? i'm still a novice at programming. I'm only good at HTML, CSS and a little javascript. This is the last bit i have left to do on this project and tomorrow is actually the deadline. please help! i'll give you access to the files if you need.@melsi

Comment: Where will you be putting the `default.php` file? You want to modify the k2 module to show the map or show it on a separate page elsewhere without necessarily having the module there?

Comment: @ilias the default.php file comes from a k2 plugin directory plugin/k2/swtabspro/tmpl/default. SwTabs is the plugin i use to generate tabs on the site. I have no problem displaying the map on other content in tabs on the website. I just need to find a way to call and output the information for each specific item and display it in a popup within the map. Here's a demo to the website http://visuarch.net/dovecot/index.php/burial-list/item/19-george-ramsay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, see below:

```
var content = "<ul>";
        <?php foreach ($item2->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
            <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>
            content += "<li class='<?php echo ($key%2) ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>'>";
                <?php if($extraField->type == 'header'): ?>
                content += "<h4 class='itemExtraFieldsHeader'><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></h4>";
                <?php else: ?>
                content += "<span class='itemExtraFieldsLabel'><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</span>";
                content += "<span class='itemExtraFieldsValue'><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>";
                <?php endif; ?>
            content += "</li>";
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    content += "</ul>";

var popup = L.popup()
.setContent(content).openOn(map);
```

Comment: Why use Javascript `setContent` when you could just load the content directly in HTML...? This code doesn't even provide real-time updates...

Comment: @JohnWHSmith setContent is what the leaflet map system uses to display content in a popup bubble. The map itself is in javascript, so what i've do is to display the content within the javascript map where i want it.